# Can i get a SUM(Qte) in incremental manner

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I need a special sql request for JET4, i have a table with three columns like that: `(ID,Price,Qte)`. Can i get a `SUM(Qte)` in incremental manner.
for example:

```
ID| Price |Qte | QteLevel
1 | 10.2  |5   | 5 
2 | 11    |8   | 5+8 =13
3 | 9     |25  | 13+25 = 38
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in MS Access using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.qte) from table as t2 where t2.id <= t.id) as QteLevel
from table as t;
```

SQL Server (like most databases) support window functions that are much more efficient for this type of operation.

Comment: I have a table with more then 200K rows(long time for this query), this query just work correctly,  then are  there  specials functions or ...

Comment: i have found intersting Function: DSUM

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
select *, (select sum(Qte) from tbl t2 where t2.id <= t.id) as QteLevel from tbl t
```

Comment: While this may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation will help the current and future readers to understand your answer even better.